# HPDF_SetCompressionMode() not working in Libharu

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, zlib, libharu

I am generating Pdf files using ***LibHaru*** libraries. My code is following

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hpdf.h"


using namespace std;

void error_handler(HPDF_STATUS   error_no,  HPDF_STATUS   detail_no, void *user_data)
{
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Compression"<<endl;

    HPDF_Doc pdf = HPDF_New(error_handler, NULL);

    if (!pdf) 
        return 0;
    HPDF_STATUS Status = HPDF_SetCompressionMode(pdf, HPDF_COMP_ALL);


    return 0;
}
```

**PROBLEM:** I debugged the code and found that `HPDF_SetCompressionMode()` ***returns 4129***, which is the error code for **Invalid value set when invoking HPDF_SetCommpressionMode().** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you step into the code, you will see you are getting the error because the ZLIB compression library was not compiled into your copy of HaruPDF.

First: comment out this line in **..\win32\include\hpdf_config.h**:

```
/* zlib is not available */
//#define LIBHPDF_HAVE_NOZLIB
```

Second: find, download and unzip the ZLIB code. You can obtain the source from the following Website:

> http://www.zlib.net/

Third: tell HaruPDF where it can find the ZLIB code, and recompile HaruPDF.

You should now be able to use compression.

Ain't Open Source grand?